# Как правильно «переключать» фрагменты?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Здравствуйте!

Имеется три фрагмента, для определенности, пусть это будут `FragmentOne`, `FragmentTwo` и `FragmentThree`. Есть активность, которая должна отображать один из этих трех фрагментов. Есть `Navigation drawer`, по нажатию на пункт которого, должен отображаться выбранный фрагмент.

В каждом из фрагментов имеется `RecyclerView`, который содержит данные. Переключение фрагментов необходимо реализовать с сохранением находящейся в них информации **и ее состояния** (например, необходимо сохранить место, до которого пользователь прокрутил список).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно это реализовать?

Про `savedinstancestate(...)` знаю, но с помощью этого метода нельзя же сохранить место прокрутки (можно, конечно, запомнить номер текущего элемента в списке, а потом промотать до него, но а если пользователь остановился где-то посередине `view`?).

Скорее мне необходим метод `setRetainInstance(true)`, но, даже с помощью него, данные фрагмента не сохраняются. Видимо это происходит из-за того, что я как-то неправильно управляю `FragmentManager`.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение таково:

```
public void showFragment(String fragmentName) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    // Получаем список фрагментов, которые находятся в FragmentManager
    ArrayList<Fragment> existingFragments = (ArrayList<Fragment>) fragmentManager.getFragments();

    // Фрагмент, который в данный момент отображен на экране
    Fragment shownFragment = null;

    if(existingFragments != null) {
        for(Fragment curFragment : existingFragments) {
            if(curFragment.isVisible()) {
                shownFragment = curFragment;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Фрагмент, который необходимо отобразить на экране
    Fragment neededFragment = null;

    // Если в данный момент на экране не отображен ни один фрагмент, либо отображен, но не тот, который требуется показать
    if(shownFragment == null || !shownFragment.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(fragmentName)) {

        // Проверяем, есть ли фрагмент, который нужно отобразить, в FragmentManager
        if(shownFragment != null)
            neededFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentName);

        // Если нужного фрагмента нет, то создаем его и добавляем в FragmentManager
        if(neededFragment == null) {
            switch(fragmentName) {
                case "FragmentOne":
                    neededFragment = new FragmentOne();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, neededFragment, "FragmentOne");
                    break;
                case "FragmentTwo":
                    neededFragment = new FragmentTwo();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, neededFragment, "FragmentTwo");
                    break;
                case "FragmentThree":
                    neededFragment = new FragmentThree();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, neededFragment, "FragmentThree");
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Скрываем старый фрагмент
        if(shownFragment != null)
            fragmentTransaction.hide(shownFragment);

        // Показываем новый фрагмент
        fragmentTransaction.show(neededFragment);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сохранить/восстановить позицию скролла можно так:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.d("TAG", "onSaveInstanceState");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("Constants.BundleKeys.BUNDLE_RECYCLER_LAYOUT", recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("TAG", "onCreateView");

    ...

    if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() == null) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    }

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Parcelable savedRecyclerLayoutState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("Constants.BundleKeys.BUNDLE_RECYCLER_LAYOUT");
        recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(savedRecyclerLayoutState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А не подскажите, как еще сделать так, чтобы `onSaveInstanceState(...)` вызывался? Активность ведь у меня в одном и том же состоянии во время переключения фрагментов находится.

Comment: @s8am, вроде, если вы фрагменты будете через `replace` заменять, то этот метод вызовется

Comment: У меня он не вызывается, хотя заменяю фрагменты через `replace`. Мне кажется, что я как-то неправильно их переключаю: http://pastebin.com/DEj5MNQn

Comment: @s8am, этот сайт у меня заблокирован. Возможно, вам стоит пойти иначе и не реплейсить фрагменты в таком случае, а скрывать/показывать

Comment: Спасибо! С hide/save все работает как и требовалось. Добавил в стартовый пост решение, может быть, кому-нибудь оно пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

Вам отлично подойдет `ViewFlipper` :) Это идеальный вариант для вашей задачи! Он как раз сохраняет состояние прокрутки и данные при переключении не теряются. Например, чтобы создать его с двумя `TextView`:

```
<ViewFlipper
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
...
...
/>

<TextView
...
...
/>

</ViewFlipper>
```

Чтобы сменить экран в `java` вызывайте

```
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
```

Только запомните, что `0` - это **первый** дочерний фрагмент в `ViewFlipper`. Соответственно, `1` - это **второй** и так далее :)

**UPD**

Если элементов много и все они содержат много контента есть еще `ViewPager` - о нем много информации на русском

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но меня интересуют именно фрагменты (в той реализации, которая в первом посте, без `ViewFlipper`, `ViewPager` и иже с ними).

Comment: @s8am, а что мешает использовать его для фрагментов?

Comment: Я несколько непонятно выразился. Основная задача `ViewPager` -- это пролистывание чего-либо. Мне этот функционал не нужен. Мне необходимо, что фрагменты менялись только по нажатиям на соответствующие пункты в меню.

Comment: @s8am, так меняйте) Поставьте слушатель на список в `NavigationDrawer` и вызывайте `setDisplayedChild(position);`. И какая прокрутка? `ViewFlipper` это контейнер для возможности отображения разных view на одном экране. Почитайте, пожалуйста) Вы ошибаетесь где-то. Я сам его использую для четырех списков и при переходе на другие экраны прокрутка сохраняется и данные (прогресс прогрессбара) не теряется. А насчет управления вашими тремя экранами. Навигацию можно хоть где вызывать. Вообщем, попробуйте