# Как заменять фрагменты?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть 2 фрагмента.

Первый фрагмент имеет 1 `TextView` и 1 кнопку, второй фрагмент имеет 1 `TextView` , `EditText` и 1 кнопку.

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопки они чередовались?

Т.е сначала открывается активность и на ней отображается 1-ый фрагмент, при нажатии на кнопку , появляется 2-ой фрагмент(при нажатии на кнопку) , опять открывается 1-ый фрагмент, и так допустим какое-то определенное количество раз, пусть будет 10.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Недавно сам задавался подобным [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558273/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B).

В итоге был написан такой метод:

```
public void showFragment(String fragmentName) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    // Получаем список фрагментов, которые находятся в FragmentManager
    ArrayList<Fragment> existingFragments = (ArrayList<Fragment>) fragmentManager.getFragments();

    // Фрагмент, который в данный момент отображен на экране
    Fragment shownFragment = null;

    if(existingFragments != null) {
        for(Fragment curFragment : existingFragments) {
            if(curFragment.isVisible()) {
                shownFragment = curFragment;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Фрагмент, который необходимо отобразить на экране
    Fragment neededFragment = null;

    // Если в данный момент на экране не отображен ни один фрагмент, либо отображен, но не тот, который требуется показать
    if(shownFragment == null || !shownFragment.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(fragmentName)) {

        // Проверяем, есть ли фрагмент, который нужно отобразить, в FragmentManager
        if(shownFragment != null)
            neededFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentName);

        // Если нужного фрагмента нет, то создаем его и добавляем в FragmentManager
        if(neededFragment == null) {
            switch(fragmentName) {
                case "FragmentOne":
                    neededFragment = new FragmentOne();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, neededFragment, "FragmentOne");
                    break;
                case "FragmentTwo":
                    neededFragment = new FragmentTwo();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, neededFragment, "FragmentTwo");
                    break;
                case "FragmentThree":
                    neededFragment = new FragmentThree();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, neededFragment, "FragmentThree");
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Скрываем старый фрагмент
        if(shownFragment != null)
            fragmentTransaction.hide(shownFragment);

        // Показываем новый фрагмент
        fragmentTransaction.show(neededFragment);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Тебе нужно реализовать намерение, то есть `intent`.

Сперва даешь через `intent` во 2 активность и там производишь свои функции. Для более подробного ответа поставь исходник напишу по нему

Comment: intent чего?

У меня фрагмент.
Нужен более подробный ответ

Comment: какая разница у тебя фрагмент или что intent действие для более подробного ответа нужен код а то твои условия я не совсем понел,ты суть не можешь донести

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?